# Wont let me backup iPod because not enough storage

Tags: backup, ipod

My iPod has not been backed up in six weeks. And I need 5 GB to back it up.  5 GB is my max storage. I don't want to have to delete everything i got to back it up. What do I do? Please help.

Comment: Have you never set it up with your computer? You'll find that has considerably more than 5GB of backup space... otherwise, you need to pay for more cloud space or throw things away

Comment: No. I haven't. I am trying to backup it with the computer and it will not work. There is no way I am throwing things away. I would have to throw everything away then. I doubt my dad would pay for more storage or my mother.

Comment: I'd hope he'd pay for your mother, even if not for more storage ;-) You'll have to go into more detail than 'won't work' for anybody to know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Backup your iPod to your computer rather than iCloud. iTunes will do that for you, see the "Back up using iTunes" section here
http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203977

There are also third party tools that may help if iTunes fails. I used TouchCopy, and it worked well.
http://www.wideanglesoftware.com/touchcopy/